# Can I utilize cisco router features during local to local data transmission?

Tags: cisco, port-forwarding

Cisco router is reachable from the internet, external ports are being forwarded to different inside hosts. From external connection on port `1234`, it is being forwarded to a internal host `10.0.0.1` running an app on port `443`. This whole can be reached from the internet via `mydomain.com:1234`.

What I need: Be able to reach this host from the inside on port `1234`,
preferably on the `internal IP` of the host and not on the external (isp) ip of the router. Currently neither one works.

```
(this works)
internet --> mydomain.com:1234 --> router --> host 10.0.0.1:443

(that does not works) hairpining?! no idea how to set it up
local    --> mydomain.com:1234 --> router --> host 10.0.0.1:443

(is this possible some how???? preferred solution)
local    --> 10.0.0.1:1234 --> router --> host 10.0.0.1:443

(works but its not really a solution)
local    --> 10.0.0.1:443 --> router --> host 10.0.0.1:443
```

I'm using `cisco isr ois xe 16.09`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions hidden in your post, I'll try to answer them all. But first look at current "solution" and how it works.

1. `External host` tries to reach `mydomain.com:1234`.
2. Host asks DNS server for IP address of `mydomain.com`, DNS reply `external IP address` of the router.
3. Host send data to `external IP address:1234`, router receives that and

   - forwards data to host `10.0.0.1:443`
   - NAT used (changed IP address from `external IP` to `local IP 10.0.0.1`)
   - port-forwarding used (changed port `1234` into `443`)

---

You are trying to achieve 3 different things, let split them:

1. Connect from `local IP address` to `local IP address`. Because they are both in local network in same subnet - you can use [how to check](https://www.meridianoutpost.com/resources/etools/network/two-ips-on-same-network.php), the request **will not go to the default gateway** (to the router) and instead the host will be contacted directly.

   - **To clearly clarify:** With mask `255.255.255.0 (/24)`, **You won't be able to send from local IP** (e.g. `10.0.0.100`) **to local IP** (`10.0.0.1`) **VIA ROUTER** unless you move either of host to different IP range/subnet.
2. Translate `mydomain.com` into `local IP address` for local host(s). There are more solutions, one of them is to configure your local DNS server and create `type A` entry for `mydomain.com`->`local IP`. If you don't have one, on your host (PC?), you can edit [hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/).
3. Last thing is to translate port `1234` into `443`. Normally you would do this thing on the router (when going from different subnets). However in this case you are on same local network for both source/destination and this won't help you. There are workarounds, e.g. using Proxy app on your machine.

   - Also there is workaround for Linux machines, you can modify IP table of that machine:

     - `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:443`